# Smooth bijective mapping between the world of quantum mechanics and that of statistics

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, stochastic-processes, quantum-mechanics

To formalize the title - I'm looking for a smooth, bijective mapping between the space of linear maps between the $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ unit sphere and itself, and the space of linear maps between $(0,1)^\infty$ and itself. I wouldn't even know where to begin looking for something like that, or what it'd be called in more idiomatic language, so vocabulary lessons would also be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I follow the relevance to quantum mechanics. Can you do it for "2" instead of "$\infty$"?

Comment: In quantum mechanics, we have time-evolution operators derived from the Hamiltonian on the space of normalizable functions - i.e. those that rest on the surface of an infinite-dimensional complex-valued sphere. And no - the problem generalizes nearly trivially, and conversely doesn't meaningfully simplify. @BruceET

Comment: Okay, actually reducing it to 2 did help some. I'm really looking for a smooth, bijective mapping between the unit $n$-sphere and the unit $n$-box. Whiiich might not exist, hm.

Comment: Quite possibly I understand too little of this to be of help, but here goes. To get from square to circle: Let center of square be the origin. Then distances from origin to boundary vary between $1/2$ and $\sqrt{2}/2;$ stretch them all to 1. And other points along each ray, proportionately.